# WooCommerce keep stock levels in sync

Tags: woocommerce

I've disabled the unique sku requirement. The reason for this is we sell the same item with different titles, photos, brand name etc but our logistics provider requires us to send the same sku.

It all works perfectly, the only issue is when our logistics provider syncs the stock levels only one of the duplicate sku products gets updated.

I was planning on writing a hook for `woocommerce_product_set_stock` to sync it across all products with that sku, however this could end up in an infinite loop.

What is the best approach?

Comment: Are you using any import plugin or in-bult woocommerce product import option to sync the stock level.?

Comment: No it's a third party integration which uses the woocommerce api.

Comment: Creating a product via API has a hook, you can use that to update stock based on SKU `do_action( "woocommerce_rest_insert_{$this->post_type}", $post, $request, true );`

Comment: So just do a check for the re-entrancy and ignore it, right? I believe all the hooks are synchronous, so just set a flag that you are processing updates, and ignore any calls to the hook until you are done.